# Replace placeholder text in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

What would be the best way to replace [placeholder] text in Google Sheets?

I've created a [demo Google Sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13abikWfU6haPgfS0zDpXX3CUWBo8aAeisdaMTEI0Yl8/edit?usp=sharing).

I'd like to be able to use the word 'Coke' in `B1` and replace all the `[Brand-Name]` placeholders.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to just type into a new cell (see `B6`) and not have to worry about messing up a formula.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can either use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>:**

[image: 0]

**or you can hardcode all instances with formulas referencing the B1:**

```
="Homepage | Journey | "&B1
```

[image: 0]